# How the function of the class itself has a different address from its objects' functions' addresses?

Tags: c++, member-functions

I know in classes that each object's variables will have a different address in memory. However, member functions' addresses are common between objects, so only one function is loaded in memory with a common address.

The issue is I was trying to print the address of a certain member function of the class itself and I expected it to be the same as the member function's address of all objects. But I found that it's different from them!! That was very strange for me.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
class LuckyNum {
    public:
        void PrintAddress() {
            printf("\tFunction address :%p\n", &LuckyNum::PrintAddress);
        }
};
    
int main() {
    LuckyNum r1;
    cout << "r1:\n";
    r1.PrintAddress();

    LuckyNum r2;
    cout << "r2:\n";
    r2.PrintAddress();

    cout << "LuckyNum Class:\n";
    printf("\tFunction address :%p\n", &LuckyNum::PrintAddress);

    return 0;
}

/*Output!! :
r1:
    Function address :0000007acdbffda0
r2:
    Function address :0000007acdbffda0
LuckyNum Class:
    Function address :0000007acdbffde0 => HOW!! it should equal the above two addresses, shouldn't it?
*/
```

Comment: Printing the address of a (non-static) member of a class using `%p` gives undefined behaviour.   Roughly speaking, an address of a member is akin to an offset relative to an instance of a class, not an address in memory.

Comment: I do not understand "function of the class itself", "its object's function addresses", or "member function's address of all objects". Please explain this meaningless terminology.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is being asked here, but I think you could drop the "data address" from the output without negatively impacting your question. Removing distractions often helps readers understand a question.

Comment: It seems an interesting exercise to see how this behavior arises from the ABI (even though it's of course undefined at the language level).  What platform is this, though?  It doesn't seem quite right either for Itanium or MS x64 ABIs...

Comment: @DavisHerring Looks like gcc or clang on Windows to me. What happens is that a pointer-to-member size is 16 bytes, which the ABI deems too big to be passed by value. So its *address* is passed to printf and is happily printed with %p.

Answer (score 3):

The function call

```
printf("\tFunction address :%p\n", &LuckyNum::PrintAddress);
```

invokes undefined behaviour. `printf` is not typesafe, and `&LuckyNum::PrintAddress` is not a pointer. It is a *pointer to member*, which is a very different thing and it's representation is implementation defined.
See the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

class LuckyNum {
public:
    std::vector<char> getAddress() {
        auto const address = &LuckyNum::getAddress;
        std::vector<char> result(sizeof(address));
        std::memcpy(result.data(), &address, sizeof(address));
        return result;
    }
};
 
int main() {
    LuckyNum r;
    auto address = r.getAddress();
 
    auto const address2 = &LuckyNum::getAddress;
    if (address.size() != sizeof(address2)) {
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
        return -1;
    }
    int result = std::memcmp(address.data(), &address2, address.size());
    if (result != 0) {
        std::cout << "Fail\n";
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "Success\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The `getAddress()` function stores the pointer to member `&LuckyNum::getAddress` in a vector of bytes and returns it. `main` then obtains one pointer to member via the `getAddress()` function and another one directly via `&LuckyNum::getAddress`. Then it compares to the byte by byte and [if you run the program](https://godbolt.org/z/qfT83jxEj) (with gcc at least) you will find that the two pointers to member are indeed equal.